# How do I implement "this" into my Java program?

Tags: java

It's a requirement of my school assignment that I use "this" in the following program. However, I can't quite figure out where I could put this. I keep getting a "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context" error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrimeNumber
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
      System.out.println("Enter the upper limit for the prime numbers computation: ");
      int upperLimit = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
      int count = 0;
      for(int number = 2; number<=upperLimit; number++)
      {
          if(isPrime(number))
          {
              System.out.println(number);
              count++;
          }
      }
      System.out.println("Number of primes generated: " + count);
    }
    public static boolean isPrime(int number)
    {
        for(int i=2; i<number; i++)
        {
           if(number%i == 0)
           {
               return false; 
           }
        }
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, `this` always references an object.  Unfortunately, you're not using any objects in your code, other than a small few whose classes are part of the JDK. I don't see how you can possibly meet the requirements of this assignment, and I wonder what your teacher was actually thinking.

Answer (score 1):

The Java keyword `this` refers to the instance of your class that invoked an instance method. A static method is general to its class, and so you cannot reference any instance (non-static) variables from within it. You can only access instance variables like `this` from within an instance method, that is, a method that is not defined as `static`.

So, you would need to create an instance method (of which there are none in your class), in order to use `this`.

Answer (score 0):

`This` is nothing more than a reference to the object on which the method was called. `Static` methods on the other hand can operate without any instance of the class even exisiting, therefore they can't have reference to any object. That's why you can't use `this` in `static` method. If you really need `this`, you have to remove `static` keywords from your functions and use instance variables in those functions anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PrimeNumber
{
    public int count = 0;
    public int upperLimit;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        PrimeNumber pn = new PrimeNumber();
        System.out.println("Enter the upper limit for the prime numbers computation: ");
        pn.upperLimit = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        pn.doCheck();
        System.out.println("Number of primes generated: " + pn.count);
    }

    public void doCheck() {
        for (int number = 2; number <= this.upperLimit; number++)
        {
            if (this.isPrime(number))
            {
                System.out.println(number);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    public boolean isPrime(int number)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
        {
            if (number % i == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```